# How to count characters in RichEdit without two characters that every new line gives?

Tags: delphi, character, richedit, line-breaks

I have problem with counting characters in richedit (Delphi XE). 
For every new line as a result i get two characters more but in text they not exists.

Example: Here are 15 characters, but richedit gives 17 because of new line.

```
line zero
line one
```

Is there solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You might get more replies and upvotes if you edit your question to include a code snippet to show how you're counting the characters currently.  (In general if you have a problem, it's normally best to show what you're currently doing as well as what the problem is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove CR/LFs and get the count of the remaining characters. An example:

```
NumChars := Length(StringReplace(RichEdit1.Text, sLineBreak, '', [rfReplaceAll]));
```

Comment: I believe what this will be 2..3 times slower compared with iteration over `Lines`. @OP: right name for pieces of text, delimited by sLineBreak is "paragraph"

Comment: @Downvoter - If the text is any longer then as in the question, you might very well be correct.

Comment: Works fine with smaller text, but it is slow with big text. But, you helped me a lot :)